# api level 19: instrumention permission error

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation

I need seed sms or add contact in my testcase.

And my apk been tested have all these permission. My instrumentation can run smoothly on prior version.

I try to test my apk on Android 4.4 .

Throw an exception :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: xxx from uid 10056 not allowed to perform WRITE_CALL_LOG
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:536)
at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1282)
at com.app.test.justTestCase.clearCallLog(justTestCase.java:76)
at com.app.test.justTestCase.test(justTestCase.java:72)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```